# A photo showing the point of view of a celebrity going down from an airstair and facing a crowd of photographers

Tags: black-and-white, history, photographer

I saw a photo and I am looking for its author, he/she was not credited in the book I saw.

I do not know whether the photo is famous.

The photo is black and white. It is taken from the point of view of a celebrity (an actress?) going down on an airstair. At end of the airstair, on the runway, there are a lot of photographers waiting for the celebrity and shooting at him/her. The photo was probably taken in the sixties.

Comment: Try using Google search and set to images. Set date range and apply key terms. This can give give dozens (or hundreds) of images that match the terms and allow rapid skimming. Search on eg aircraft exit, aircraft stairs, press, aircraft, photographers kennedy, ... pope ..., aircraft arrives , ...

Answer (score 8):

The best thing you can do is shoot a photograph of it, crop it, then go to [google image search](https://www.google.com/imghp) and upload it through clicking the small camera icon. Google will try to find similar pictures hopefully helping you to find the image.

I doubt we can help you much beyond that with such a vague description.

Comment: that's awesome!

Answer (score 2):

You could try looking on the "iconic photos" blog. I think I know the photo you're talking about and I think it's Jackie Kennedy in the photo (and the airline is Pan-Am). But anyway, check here... at the very least you'll get to browse one of the more interesting photo blogs on the web...

http://iconicphotos.wordpress.com/